# How Can I Connect CodeArtifact to Confluent.io Maven Repo?

Tags: aws-codeartifact, maven-repository

AWS CodeArtifact has a list of supported external connection repositories listed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/external-connection.html#supported-public-repositories

I need CodeArtifact to host packages hosted at https://packages.confluent.io/maven/.  This repo is not in the list of supported repositories.  What's the best way for me to make CodeArtifact host these packages?